# Issue with Invoke-AzResourceAction cmdlet with a function wrapper

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-hdinsight

I want to set certificate for Azure HDInsight for Azure DataLake access. I am following the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-store#refresh-the-hdinsight-certificate-for-data-lake-storage-gen1-access) to and using the Invoke-AzResourceAction cmdlet.

I would like to know, why the code works without a function wrapper and fails with a function wrapper. I am not changing the azure subscription. No changes at all, the code just fails.

The below code works fine:

```
### Example Preparation​
# see $HDInsightDefinition.ResourceGroupName​
$resourceGroupName = "PL-Pilot"
​
# see $HDInsightDefinition.ClusterName​
$clusterName = "plhd01-hdi"
​
# see $HDInsightDefinition.ServicePrincipalObject.ApplicationId.Guid​
$appId = "280f3a19-ed77-45c"
​
### get cert details from common keyvault​
# common key vault is available using $HDInsightDefinition.CommonKeyVaultId​
$certStringSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -Name ("spuucert-{0}" -f $appId) -ResourceId /subscriptions/49e1-a2a6-58ee4a3dd124/resourceGroups/coe-eu-commons/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/eu-commons
$certPasswordSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -Name ("sppwd-{0}" -f $appId) -ResourceId /subscriptions/49e1-a2a6-58ee4a3dd124/resourceGroups/coe-eu-commons/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/eu-commons
​
​
### update hdi cluster, if cluster already exists and wasn't created immediately before (as in this case, it has the correct identity certificate)​
# => $HDInsightDefinition.ClusterAlreadyExists​
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-data-lake-store#refresh-the-hdinsight-certificate-for-data-lake-storage-gen1-access​
Invoke-AzResourceAction `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters' `
    -ResourceName $clusterName `
    -ApiVersion '2015-03-01-preview' `
    -Action 'updateclusteridentitycertificate' `
    -Parameters @{ ApplicationId = $appId; Certificate = $certStringSecret.SecretValueText; CertificatePassword = $certPasswordSecret.secretvaluetext } `
    -Force
```

However, when I wrap the above code inside a function in our framework, the code fails. I can confirm that there is no issue with the parameters. The '$HDInsightDefinition' object will contain the same parameter values that were passed to the above code (without function wrapper)

```
function Update-XtoHDInsightCertificate {
    param 
    (
        [Parameter (ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        $HDInsightDefinition
    )

    $appid = $HDInsightDefinition.ServicePrincipalObject.ApplicationId.Guid
    $certStringSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -Name ("spuucert-{0}" -f $appid) -ResourceID $HDInsightDefinition.CommonKeyVaultId
    $certPasswordSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -Name ("sppwd-{0}" -f $appid) -ResourceID $HDInsightDefinition.CommonKeyVaultId
    $resourceGroupName = $HDInsightDefinition.ResourceGroupName.tostring()
    $ClusterName = $HDInsightDefinition.ClusterName.tostring()

    # Update the certificate identity of HDInsight Cluster for DataLake Access
    Invoke-AzResourceAction `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters' `
    -ResourceName $ClusterName `
    -ApiVersion '2015-03-01-preview' `
    -Action 'updateclusteridentitycertificate' `
    -Parameters @{ ApplicationId = $appid; Certificate = $certStringSecret.SecretValueText; CertificatePassword = $certPasswordSecret.SecretValueText } `
    -Force

    write-CoeLog ("Successfully updated certificate for the HDINsight Cluster: {0}" -f $ClusterName)
}
```

I am getting the below error. I got the details using the 'Resolve-AzError' cmdlet.

```
 Resolve-AzError
Breaking changes in the cmdlet 'Resolve-AzError' :
 - The `Resolve-Error` alias will be removed in a future release.  Please change any scripts that use this alias to use `Resolve-AzError` instead.


NOTE : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other information on breaking changes in Azure PowerShell.


   HistoryId: 4


Message        : {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet()
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
Exception      : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Entities.ErrorResponses.ErrorResponseMessageException
InvocationInfo : {Invoke-AzResourceAction}
Line           :     Invoke-AzResourceAction `

Position       : At C:\Users\manjug\source\repos\eXtollo_April_23_2\coe-df\Continuous Deployment\Deployment\eXtolloInstance\HDInsight_1\HDInsightTools.psm1:17 char:5
                 +     Invoke-AzResourceAction `
                 +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
HistoryId      : 4



   HistoryId: 1


RequestId      : d6579b01-bb55-4249-b555-1e0d462a7c6e
Message        : Resource group 'non-existent-rg-12345' could not be found.
ServerMessage  : ResourceGroupNotFound: Resource group 'non-existent-rg-12345' could not be found. (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudError])
ServerResponse : {NotFound}
RequestMessage : {GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/3e959272-bef3-49e1-a2a6-58ee4a3dd124/resourceGroups/non-existent-rg-12345/resources?api-version=2019-07-01}
InvocationInfo : {Get-AzResource}
Line           :             $null = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName non-existent-rg-12345 -Name non-existent-resource-32541 -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue

Position       : At C:\Users\manjug\source\repos\eXtollo_April_23_2\coe-df\Continuous Deployment\Framework\CoreDeployment.psm1:6957 char:21
                 + ...     $null = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName non-existent-rg-12345 - ...
                 +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet()
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
HistoryId      : 1


The Azure PowerShell team is listening, please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azpssurvey?Q_CHL=ERROR.
```

Comment: Did you checked whether the output of `$HDInsightDefinition.ResourceGroupName.tostring()´ returns your actual resource group name? The error message says, the ressource group doesn't exisist....

Comment: yes, it returns the same resource group name.

Comment: update: If i hard code the values, '$appid', '$resourcegroupname' and '$clustername' inside the function. It works.

Comment: Can you try to omit the toString() on $HDInsightDefinition.ResourceGroupName ? Also check the type using ```$appid.GetType()```

Comment: I omitted the 'toString()' and '$appid', '$resourcegroupname' and '$clustername' are 'String'

Comment: hm, strange. Do they contain any whitespace characters?

Comment: I am able to solve it. I did a typecast for the variables. 
[String]$appid = $HDInsightDefinition.ServicePrincipalObject.ApplicationId.Guid
[String]$resourceGroupName = $HDInsightDefinition.ResourceGroupName
[String]$ClusterName = $HDInsightDefinition.ClusterName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve it. I did a typecast for the variables. 
[String]$appid = $HDInsightDefinition.ServicePrincipalObject.ApplicationId.Guid [String]$resourceGroupName = $HDInsightDefinition.ResourceGroupName [String]$ClusterName = $HDInsightDefinition.ClusterName

Comment: Does Type casting a variable to [String] and converting the result using 'toString()' are different??

Comment: Hi @ManjunathRao Glad to know that issue has been resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.